# String splitting in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle10g

I have a table like this in oracle:

```
servername       description                                                    ObjectState
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
vm1         SP LA -  W IN  S V R S #P19 99 9999 999999 999  QTY 1                   0
VM2         S PL A - V R STD #P29-9 9 99 QTY 2 : SPLVRENT #P3 999999 9 QTY 3        1
```

etc I want the output like this

```
servername   description             ponumber                  qty     objectstate
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
vm1          SP LA -  W IN  S V R S  P19 99 9999 999999 999    1        0
vm2          S PL A - V R STD        P29-9 9 99                2        1
vm2          SPLVRENT                P3 999999 9               3        1
```

help me how to do this using pl/sql stored procedure

Comment: What is the logic that you want to implement (i.e. how do you know where one column begins and another ends)?  Should we use the first `#` character and the string `QTY`?  And then any `:` starts a new logical row?  with only two rows of data, it's hard to guess at how to generalize your rules.

Comment: @anand krishna What have you tried so far. Please post that also, so that we can improve your code

Answer (score 0):

Try this Procedure!!

This will work if the description pattern will be the same with the spaces specified and the flow like description,phonenum,Qty

```
create or replace procedure sp_split_str
as
     end_pos number:=0;
     strt_pos number :=1;
     CNT NUMBER:=0;
     v_desc varchar(200);
begin
     for i in (select * from table) loop
            if(instr(i.description,':',1,1)=0) then
                   dbms_output.put_line('Server Name : '||i.servername);
                   dbms_output.put_line('Description : '||substr(i.description,1,instr(i.description,'#',1,1)-2));
                   dbms_output.put_line('Phone Number : '||substr(i.description,instr(i.description,'#',1,1)+1,instr(i.description,'Q',-1,1)-2-instr(i.description,'#',1,1)));
                   dbms_output.put_line('Qty : '||substr(i.description,instr(i.description,'Q',-1,1)+4));           
                   dbms_output.put_line('Object State : '||i.objectstate);
            else
                   for J in 1..(length(i.description)-length(replace(i.description,':','')))+1 loop
                          IF(J=1) THEN
                                 end_pos := instr(i.description,':',1,1);
                                 v_desc := substr(i.description,strt_pos,end_pos-2);
                          ELSE
                                 end_pos := instr(i.description,':',1,j);
                                 strt_pos := instr(i.description,':',1,j-1);
                          END IF;
                          dbms_output.put_line('Server Name : '||i.servername);
                          dbms_output.put_line('Description : '||substr(v_desc,1,instr(v_desc,'#',1,1)-2));
                          dbms_output.put_line('Phone Number : '||substr(v_desc,instr(v_desc,'#',1,1)+1,instr(v_desc,'Q',-1,1)-2-instr(v_desc,'#',1,1)));
                          dbms_output.put_line('Qty : '||substr(v_desc,instr(v_desc,'Q',-1,1)+4));          
                          dbms_output.put_line('Object State : '||i.objectstate);

                          CNT := CNT+1;
                          IF(CNT=J) THEN
                                  v_desc := substr(i.description,strt_pos+2);
                          ELSE
                                  v_desc := substr(i.description,strt_pos+2,end_pos-2);
                          END IF;
                   END loop;
            end if;
      END LOOP;

END;
```